# Why am I getting errors in jdoconfig.xml?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd, jdo

Eclipse marker tab shows some `xml` problem. This occurred when I checked `dynamic web module` in the `Project Facets`.

This is my project hierarchy :

[image]

`jdconfig.xml` (automatically generated) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">

   <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
       <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
       value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true"/>
   </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

Errors shown in the marker window :

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jdoconfig'.
```

What is the reason I am getting this error ?

Also,what is `jdoconfig.xml` ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because its wrong?
This page has a simple example
http://db.apache.org/jdo/jdoconfig_dtd.html

The documentation of any JDO implementation would explain what that file is for, as would a simple internet search.

A better XML header would be something like

```
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The answer from Protoxy worked for me.

Answer (score 32):

Try this instead

```
  <jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">
```

Comment: it has fixed the problem!

Comment: Is it possible for this answer to include _why_ this worked?  (Upvoted anyway since it did fix the problem).

Answer (score 1):

If there exists no schema as per 'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation', then removing this attribute kills this validation error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jdoconfig'.
```

This is a validation error. It says, that when validating your XML file, parser couldn't find declaration for element `<jdconfig>` on the referred schema document.

In your case it is probably caused by two different things:

1. The schemalocation `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig` is incorrect, there is no schema in that address.
2. The element `<jdconfig>` has a (default) namespace, yet the schema location refers to non-namespaced schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">
```